# What do the elements of the chains of a simplicial complex represent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've just started to learn homology and I don't quite understand why we define chains the way we do. For a simplicial complex $S$ we define $C_k$ to be the $k$-chains on $S$ given by an abelian group of integer linear combinations of $k$-simplices. Are these linear combinations formal and chosen because they give us a nice group structure to work with or do they actually correspond to something geometrically?

Comment: A chain is a sum of geometric objects. Each geometric object is easy to understand. The sum can be thought of as a union. The only tricky part is thinking about something like $2\cdot A,$ where $A$ is a geometric object. But you've seen these before implicitly a loot: counting roots with multiplicity, for instance. The idea is that oftentimes a subvariety ought to be counted with multiplicity, if you want certain formulas to be true generically. And geometrically, we see things like multiple covers which also give this multiplicity behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, the linear combinations are formal because they give you nice group structure.

Longer answer: <strike>Historically, *co*homology came before homology.</strike> (See comments below.) In the modern pedagogy, we work with homology then dualize chain complexes and introduce cohomology, and as if by magic, this dual functor has all the same qualities and has extra structure like the cup product and other operations.

But, one important thing is lost in this presentation. It's intuitive to add, scale, and take linear combinations of scalar-valued functions $\Delta \to \mathbb{Z}$. The original advent of cohomology had to do with studying the properties of integration of differential forms around closed curves that enclosed singularities, where the scalar ring was $\mathbb{R}$. Think about contour integration or residues in complex analysis. This approach yields [de Rham cohomology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/De_Rham_cohomology).

But if $f: \Delta \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$-linear), then
$$
\sum_i n_i f(\sigma_i) = f \biggl( \sum_i n_i \sigma_i \biggr),  
$$
where the second expression involves taking the linear combination on the chains, i.e. considering elements of the dual to $\mathbb{Z}[\Delta]$. There's a bit of subtlety about finiteness that's addressed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929100/the-difference-between-chains-and-cochains), but in spirit, this explains why formal linear combinations of chains and the homology theory are worthwhile to study.

Comment: *"Historically, cohomology came before homology"* is, by my understanding, not correct.

Comment: Wasn't Poincaré integrating differential forms, when he proved his key lemma, and the notions of closed and exact forms developed out of the equivalence that these suggested?

Comment: Yes, but Betti was developing simplicial homology already in 1870.

Comment: De Rham cohomology came much later than simplicial homology, historically.  Poincaré formulated simplicial homology in the 1890s (inspired by earlier ideas of Betti) but the idea of de Rham cohomology was not suggested until 1928 by Cartan (and then shortly afterwards de Rham proved it yielded the same Betti numbers as simplicial homology).

Comment: Of course there were precursors to de Rham cohomology involving things like period integrals that came much earlier but the idea of taking closed forms mod exact forms was new in 1928 as far as I know.  (I am getting my information from Dieudonné's *A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology 1900-1960*.)

Comment: Ah, I need that book.

Comment: Thank you for the history lesson. That book indeed sounds interesting.